# Jquery generate html with append() button conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scenario :

**[Example Code | JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mvx6psw/1/)**

I am building a questionnair app, Where i have many questions against one questionnair.

On the add-question page, I have one question by default and `other can be generated by jquery`.

Now `Below each question a button with name add answer` creates the maximum 4 answers for a single question.

And on the same page i have a `button for add another question`

So i do successfully generates answers(text field) for first question like wise.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 3; 
    var wrapper         = $(".addChoices"); 
    var add_button      = $("#add_field_button");
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ 
            x++; 
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-8"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Answer</label><div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4 operations"><span><input type="checkbox" name="correct"> Correct</span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: blue">Delete Choice</span></div>'); 
        }
    }); 
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

And for question generation i have code which generates question via `jquery append()`:

```
function addform(e){ //on add input button click
    var max_fields      = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".add-question-wrapper"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_question_button"); //Add button ID

        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-8"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Question Type</label>  <div class="col-md-8"><select class="form-control"><option>Text</option><option>MCQs</option></select></div></div></div></div><div class="row addChoices"><div class="col-md-8"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Question</label><div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4 operations"><span><input type="checkbox" name="correct"> Correct</span>&nbsp;| &nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: blue">Delete Choice</span></div></div><div id="add-choice"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="add_field_button">Add Choice</button></div>');
        }
    }
```

Problem :

When i generates a new question then the button for generating answers for each question in the generated question's html button's id the same with the default question button's id.

To understand it :

Button's id with default question is now equal to generated question button id are same.

Now the generated question add answer button does not works neither the default question button.

**`Problem : Button id conflict.`**

Comment: what do you mean by button's name?

Comment: I mean id ! Sorry ! I am updating the question.

Comment: @void I have updated my question Please have a look there ! JSfiddle link  will be good to understand the my shit, :(

Comment: Just append `x` to the button `id` so it is always unique. Or use a class name instead.

Comment: @GillesC I have tried almost everything, Can you please please make the changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few issues i can see there.

1. You need to use the class name instead of id `add_field_button`.
2. You need to have some `x` and `y`. Different for keeping a track of total number of questions and total number of answers differently. Instead of `x` you should calculate the number of elements present as `number of choices` should be on per question basis.
3. Wrapper should be the closest `.addChoices`

   ```
   $(document).on("click", ".add_field_button", function(e) {
   var wrapper = $(this).closest("div").prev(".addChoices");
   var _num_choices =  $(this).closest("div").prev(".addChoices").find(".singletonChoiceContainer").length;

   if (_num_choices < max_fields) {
     x++;
       wrapper.append('<div class="col-md-8 singletonChoiceContainer"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Answer</label><div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" name="" class="form-control"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4 operations"><span><input type="checkbox" name="correct"> Correct</span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: blue">Delete Choice</span></div>');
   }
   });
   ```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mvx6psw/3/)

Comment: Yes please ! My bad